# OpenCL - Method to perform a reduction

Tags: c, synchronization, opencl, atomic, reduction

From the [following post](http://simpleopencl.blogspot.fr/2013/04/performance-of-atomics-atomics-in.html), I try to implement a sum reduction of an array
with this kernel code :

```
 #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_int64_base_atomics : enable

__kernel void sumGPU ( __global const long *input, 
               __global long *finalSum
               )
 {
  uint local_id = get_local_id(0);
  uint group_size = get_local_size(0);

  // Temporary local value
  local long tempInput;

  tempInput = input[local_id];

  // Variable for final sum 
  local long totalSumIntegerPart[1];

  // Initialize sums
  if (local_id==0)
    totalSumIntegerPart[0] = 0;

  // Compute atom_add into each workGroup 
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

  atom_add(&totalSumIntegerPart[0], tempInput);

  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

  // Perform sum of each workGroup sum
  if (local_id==(get_local_size(0)-1))
    atom_add(finalSum, totalSumIntegerPart[0]);

}
```

But the value of `finalSum` is not the expected value (I have initially set the `input` array to :

```
 for (i=0; i<nWorkItems; i++)
    input[i] = i+1;
```

So, I expect with `nWorkItems = 1024` : `finalSum = nWorkItems*(nWorkItems+1)/2=524800`

And actually, I get `finalSum = 16384`.

I get this result by taking a `sizeWorkGroup = 16` and `nWorkItems = 1024`.

Strangely, with `sizeWorkGroup = 32` and `nWorkItems = 1024`, I get another value : `finalSum = 32768`

I don't understand the last instruction (which is supposed to compute the sum of each partial sum, i.e for each workgroup) :

```
// Perform sum of each workGroup sum
  if (local_id==(get_local_size(0)-1))
    atom_add(finalSum, totalSumIntegerPart[0]);
```

Indeed, I would have thought that instruction `atom_add(finalSum, totalSumIntegerPart[0]);` would be independent of the `local_id` `if condition`.

The most important is this instruction has to be executed "`number of workGroups`" times (supposing that finalSum is a shared value between all workGroups, isn't it ?).

So I thought I could replace :

```
// Perform sum of each workGroup sum
  if (local_id==(get_local_size(0)-1))
    atom_add(finalSum, totalSumIntegerPart[0]);
```

by

```
 // Perform sum of each workGroup sum
      if (local_id==0)
        atom_add(finalSum, totalSumIntegerPart[0]);
```

Anyone could help to find the right value with my parameters (`sizeWorkGroup = 16` and `nWorkItems = 1024`), i.e a `finalSum` equal to `524800` ?

or exlain to me why this final sum is not well performed ?

**UPDATE :**

Here's the kernel code on the [following link](http://simpleopencl.blogspot.fr/2013/04/performance-of-atomics-atomics-in.html) (it is slightly different from mine because `atom_add` here only increment 1 for each workitem) :

```
kernel void AtomicSum(global int* sum)

{
 local int tmpSum[1]; 
 if(get_local_id(0)==0){
 tmpSum[0]=0;}

barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);         
atomic_add(&tmpSum[0],1);         
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);    

if(get_local_id(0)==(get_local_size(0)-1)){
  atomic_add(sum,tmpSum[0]);
 }

}
```

Is this a valid kernel code, I mean, which gives good results ?

Maybe a solution could be to put at the begin of my kernel code :

```
unsigned int tid = get_local_id(0);
unsigned int gid = get_global_id(0);
unsigned int localSize = get_local_size(0);
// load one tile into local memory
int idx = i * localSize + tid;
localInput[tid] = input[idx];
```

I am going to test it and keep you informed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
tempInput = input[local_id];
```

Should be:

```
tempInput = input[get_global_id(0)];
```

You are always summing the first area of your input, which is consistent with your weird results. And why it depends on the parameters of work group size.

```
16*16*64 = 16384
32*32*32 = 32768
```

Also your code can be simplified a bit:

```
  uint local_id = get_local_id(0);

  // Variable for final sum 
  local long totalSumIntegerPart;

  // Initialize sums
  if (local_id==0)
    totalSumIntegerPart = 0;

  // Compute atom_add into each workGroup 
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);    
  atom_add(&totalSumIntegerPart, input[get_global_id(0)]);    
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

  // Perform sum of each workGroup sum
  if (local_id==0)
    atom_add(finalSum, totalSumIntegerPart);
```

And I would not abuse as you do of atomics, because they are not the most efficient way of doing reductions. You can probably get 10x more speed with proper reduction methods. However, it is ok as a PoC or for learning local memory and CL.

Comment: thanks, I understand my weird results. But from http://simpleopencl.blogspot.fr/2013/04/performance-of-atomics-atomics-in.html , they advise to work with local memory which provides better performances. I put in my update above the kernel code that they use.

Comment: You wanted to say : " atom_add(&totalSumIntegerPart, input[  get_global_id(0)]); " and not  " atom_add(&totalSumIntegerPart, input[get_global_size(0)]); " , don't you ?